# Ionic 2.0 push security profile not found error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm making android push service.

I enrolled security profile and add fcm server key and my keystore file

```
ionic security profiles list
name   |   tag    |   android    |    ios
skout90| skout90  |      V       |
```

And i requested below

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer my_api_key" -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" -d '{
"tokens": ["my_device_key"],
"profile": "skout90",
"notification": {
"message": "Alert!"
}
}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"`
```

but

I got response

```
{
  "meta": {
    "request_id": "1b855552-195e-4dd3-cd36-ae49b19490a4",
    "status": 400,
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "error": {
    "type": "BadRequest",
    "link": null,
    "message": "Security Profile 'skout90' not found."
  }
}
```

I can't find what is wrong.

What do i have to?

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself.

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer my_api_key"
```

I input wrong my_api_key.